# Cannot access to windows

Tags: windows-8, repair

Today when I turn on my computer, it cannnot start windows and stops at the loading screen:

[image]

Some minutes later, a system repair starts and it said "Checking disk for errors. This might take over an hour" and then "attemping to repair your computer". After that, it said "cannot repair your computer".

I have tried to refreshed, automatic-repair with my install disk but none of them work: after 10m I run the application, my computer suddenly stopped working.

P/S: I entered bios-setting to check for my hardrive but seem nothing wrong here, they still appear. There weren't any sign of "disk error"" ,"insert disk" (or something like that) so I personally think my hardisk didn't cause this problem.

Any advance? Pls help.

Comment: Your installation is significantly corrupt to a point Windows is unable to make changes to itself to actually successfully boot.  This doesn't happen on healthy HDDs.  If using a restoration point and/or Refresh feature does not work you don't have a great deal of options. The normal tools to a corrupt Windows installation are of limited use outside of Windows.

Comment: tks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows installation is corrupt in a vital area, therefore it cannot be repaired. Your only choice would be to reinstall Windows. You can (probably) still save your files if you are able to plug your HDD in to another computer.

Comment: I thought so too, guest I will have to reinstall my computers
BTW, great help, tks